# How to print Array of Arrays on separate lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, console.log

I have a function which groups anagrams together

```js
function groupAnagrams(strs) {
  let result = {};
  for (let word of strs) {
    let cleansed = word.split("").sort().join("");
    if (result[cleansed]) {
      result[cleansed].push(word);
    } else {
      result[cleansed] = [word];
    }
  }
  console.log(Object.values(result));
  return Object.values(result);
}
```

it prints the results in the following format

```js
[ [ 'abc', 'bac', 'cba' ], [ 'fun', 'fun', 'unf' ], [ 'hello' ] ]
```

However I would like the output to look like the following

```
abc, bac, cba

fun, fun, unf

hello
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
const data = [ [ 'abc', 'bac', 'cba' ], [ 'fun', 'fun', 'unf' ], [ 'hello' ] ]

data.forEach(row => console.log(row.join(', ')))
//or

console.log(data.map(row => row.join(', ')).join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a node.js-tagged question I'll give an example with [`os.EOL`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#oseol)

```js
const { EOL } = require('os');
const lines = [ [ 'abc', 'bac', 'cba' ], [ 'fun', 'fun', 'unf' ], [ 'hello' ] ];

const output = lines.map((words) => words.join(', ')).join(EOL);

process.stdout.write(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solutions...

```js
function groupAnagram(arr){
  arr.map((item) => {
    console.log(`${item.join(', ')} \n\n`)
  });
}

groupAnagram([ [ 'abc', 'bac', 'cba' ], [ 'fun', 'fun', 'unf' ], [ 'hello' ] ]
);
```